# How Can I configure jboss 7 structure dependencies?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I just wanna create a new folders at my jbossas 7 to reorganize the jar's dependencies, for example create a lib.jdbc and put all the jdbc specific jars there and go on.. Where i must specify this?

Ty for advance.

Comment: well, it's possible edit the file in server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml with something like that:https://community.jboss.org/thread/152431?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Just create custom modules as you need it with dependencies.

Comment: ty for answering, i'll try a tell you sth.